# Determining if end of one string is the same as beginning of another (with or without regex; Java)

Tags: java, text-alignment

I want to match the beginning of one string with the end of another string, I could not find a solution on the internet, let's say I have these sequences:

I have to sequences:

```
seq1 = AAATAAA
seq2 = AAATTTT
```

I want to check if a part of the **end** of seq1 matches a part of the **beginning**  of seq2. A test like this: 
:

```
AAATAAA
    AAATTTT  //--> so I want to match AAA

//and also check the other way around:
AAATTTT
       AAATAAA //-->no match
```

I tried to convert a string to a completely optional regex like so:

```
(A?A?A?T?T?T?T?)$ //from seq1
(A?A?A?T?A?A?A?)$ //from seq2
```

However this won't work properly:

```
(A?A?A?T?T?T?T?)$ //--> matches AAA = correct  
(A?A?A?T?A?A?A?)$ //--> matches T   = not correct!
```

This could be solved using a regex that only allows matches if the preceeding characters are matched(if possible). So if this is possible it will not match `(A?A?A?T?A?A?A?)$` because `AAA`is not matched. I would like to fix this issue using regex however **solutions which do not use regex are welcome too**!

Comment: This doesn't seem like an appropriate problem for regular expressions.

Comment: I already doubt if this was possible using regex @JonathonReinhart

Comment: I would move on. No sense trying to use a screwdriver on this nail.

Comment: Regex can only process 1 input, but you have 2. It might be possible, but please show **one** input and exactly what you want to match and capture (if anything).

Comment: Finding O(n^2) solution is trivial, you have examples in answers below. How long your sequences will be (for short ones there is no point in overcomplicating things)? Will you be doing checks on more than pair of inputs against each other - for example 1 sequence against 10 or 100 reused matches (so preprocessing can amortize its costs)?